# Select top three pairs of numbers that appear grouped together in oracle db

Tags: database, oracle

Given a `table A`, columns in the following order `(item_id, order_id, product_id)` set up like so:

```
1   1   2
2   2   4
3   3   3
4   3   6
5   4   2
6   5   5
7   6   5
8   7   1
9   7   7
10  7   9
11  8   10
12  9   1
13  5   7
14  7   5
15  6   7
16  1   1
17  4   1
18  8   3
19  3   10
```

Select the top three pairs of `product_ids` with same `order_id` using only oracle sql. I have tried self joins, subqueries and everything else but cannot seem to get anything working... If someone can get this you will be my programming idol.

So the output would be

Most occurred pair: 7 and 5 because they occur together three times second most occurred: 3,10 because they occur together twice third most occurred: 1,2 because they occur together twice

So, logically, going down the list when order_id = 1 the product_ids = 1 and 2 (so one occurrence) they occur together again when order_id = 4 When order_id = 5,6, or 7 they have 5 and 7 as product_id's so they occur 3 times... and so on

Comment: Please give sample output for the above data

Comment: What does "top three pairs of product_ids with same order_id " even mean? Can you show the required output for this input and explain how you got it?

Comment: We can see that in your requirement. What we need is your expected output with data. `top three pairs of product_ids with same order_id` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Top three pairs ascending or descending?

Comment: RubahMalam doesn't matter if they are ascending or descending

Comment: So the output would be Most occurred pair: 7 and 5 because they occur together three times second most occurred: 3,10 because they occur together twice third most occurred: 1,2 because they occur together twice So, logically, going down the list when order_id = 1 the product_ids = 1 and 2 (so one occurrence) they occur together again when order_id = 4 When order_id = 5,6, or 7 they have 5 and 7 as product_id's so they occur 3 times... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different queries (one hierarchical and the other with a self join) - both give the same answer (go for whichever is more performant):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d670c/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A (item_id, order_id, product_id) AS
          SELECT 1, 1, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 3, 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 4, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 5, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 6, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 7, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 7, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 7, 9 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 8, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 9, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 13, 5, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 14, 7, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 15, 6, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 16, 1, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 17, 4, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 18, 8, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 19, 3, 10 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT lower_product_id,
         upper_product_id,
         COUNT(1) AS frequency,
         LISTAGG( order_id, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY order_id ) AS order_ids
  FROM (
    SELECT order_id,
           lower_product_id,
           upper_product_id
    FROM (
      SELECT order_id,
             PRIOR product_id AS lower_product_id,
             product_id       AS upper_product_id,
             LEVEL            AS lvl
      FROM   A
      CONNECT BY
             PRIOR order_id = order_id
      AND    PRIOR product_id < product_id
    )
    WHERE  lvl = 2
  )
  GROUP BY lower_product_id, upper_product_id
  ORDER BY frequency DESC, lower_product_id, upper_product_id
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d670c/9/0)**:

```
| LOWER_PRODUCT_ID | UPPER_PRODUCT_ID | FREQUENCY | ORDER_IDS |
|------------------|------------------|-----------|-----------|
|                5 |                7 |         3 |   5, 6, 7 |
|                1 |                2 |         2 |      1, 4 |
|                3 |               10 |         2 |      3, 8 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT A.product_id AS lower_product_id,
         B.product_id AS upper_product_id,
         COUNT(1) AS frequency,
         LISTAGG( A.order_id, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY A.order_id ) AS order_ids
  FROM   A
         INNER JOIN A B
         ON (    A.order_id = B.order_id
             AND A.product_id < B.product_id )
  GROUP BY A.product_id, B.product_id
  ORDER BY frequency DESC, lower_product_id, upper_product_id
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d670c/9/1)**:

```
| LOWER_PRODUCT_ID | UPPER_PRODUCT_ID | FREQUENCY | ORDER_IDS |
|------------------|------------------|-----------|-----------|
|                5 |                7 |         3 |   5, 6, 7 |
|                1 |                2 |         2 |      1, 4 |
|                3 |               10 |         2 |      3, 8 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want to achieve,you can try this:

```
     select product_id,myranking from 
       (select product_id, dense_rank() over(order by mycount desc) myranking from 
         (select product_id,count(*) over (partition by product_id) mycount from mytable)) 
           where myranking<4  group by product_id,myranking
```

the output will be order_id with the most occurences at the product_id column and its rank

Comment: This is close but not order_id and item_id pair. You want the top three occurring pairs of product_id's.

Comment: Wow you are so close!!! But two things:

1. The query you wrote returns product_id = 2 as having counted 3 of them when only 2 is given.

2. You have to find a way to only count the product_id occurrence if it shows up with the other number (for example: you count product_id occurrence even if it isn't with its other pair. Think of the pair that share order_id as a single count of that pair not as individuals) Keep trying you are on the verge!! :D

Comment: and when product_id =1 you return 1 but it should return 2(product_id = 2 occurs 4 times but its highest pair is with 2 and theyoccur together 2times

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you want :

```
select item_id,order_id,product_id,
(case when order_id = product_id then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as pairs
from tableA
having pairs = 'Yes'
order by order_id asc
limit 3
```

or without using `HAVING` clause

```
select item_id,order_id,product_id
from tableA
where order_id = product_id
order by order_id asc
limit 3
```

Comment: Think of it as consolidating the table into order_id's being unique... So when order_id = 1 all the product_id values are 1 and 2 so that is one occurrence of 1 and 2. When you consolidate order_id = 5 the product_id's would be 5 and 7 so that is one occurrence of 5 and 7. That make more sense?

Comment: @user2942951 Yes, I was missunderstood your question. Why don't put desired output in question instead of put them in comment?